# Mirror and Boolean-Union operation, makes some of the vertices appear on the opposite side of the mirror

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, mirror

I'm following a hard surface modelling course.
And in the course when he makes a boolean-union, and applies it.
All the vertices stay on the same side.

My problem is, when i do that, the vertices behind the main object ends up on the opposite site of the mirror.

This is the result that i want (as in the video).
[image]

But this is the result i end up with.
Here i would have to edit the back of the cylinder on the left, and the front on the right side.
Which doesn't work with what i want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: The video being in 2.79 and yours being in 2.8+, assuming the screenshots are in the right order, the video actually looks less expectable and correct then your result. Are the screenshots reversed?

Comment: The screenshots are in correct order. I'm using 2.93, so there have through the course been some differences. But in the video it seems like he is getting more desirable results overall, so i thought my settings or something might be wrong. I need to get the same result, to be able to extrude the cylinder edge out of through the main mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on Reddit as well, and the solution was to change the **Solver** to **Fast** instead of **Exact**